# Animation up working. Animation back down not working

Tags: android

I have a menu I am trying to animate.  I am splitting a menu by changing margins
and inserting a new menu.  When I want to insert the menu, the animation is:

```
    level3Height = level3Frame.getHeight();

    final int newBottomMargin = (int)(origBottomMargin + level3Height/2);
    final int newTopMargin = (int)(origTopMargin + level3Height/2);

    splitUp = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnShopWireless.getLayoutParams();
            params.bottomMargin = (int)(newBottomMargin * interpolatedTime);
            btnShopWireless.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    joinDown = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnShopWireless.getLayoutParams();
            params.bottomMargin = (int)(origBottomMargin * interpolatedTime);
            btnShopWireless.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
    splitUp.setDuration(1000);
    splitUp.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

    joinDown.setDuration(500);
    joinDown.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
```

After getting the height of the inserted menu, the animation moves the Views upward very nicely:

```
    btnShopWireless.startAnimation(splitUp);
```

All that works great!  But....

When I want to remove the inserted level menu and move things back down I use the below, and the animation doesn't happen - the Views simply slam back into 
their original place with no smooth motion.

```
    btnShopWireless.startAnimation(joinDown);
```

I have AnimationListeners set up to setVisibility to VISIBLE onAnimationStart and also setVisibility to GONE onAnimationEnd. They are doing their job, so I know the animation is getting invoked or the visibility would never occur within the AnimationListeners for joinDown. But the animated movement backdown just never happens. I can only animate the first one, splitUp.

Anyone have any clues as to what I am missing in order to get the second animation working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was - pure IQ underflow.

The originalMargin was 0. I increased them to about 190dp to fit in a 3rd menu. When it time to bring the menu together and remove the 3rd menu, the transformation used the original margins again multiplied by the time value. No matter how much time or which interpolator, the originalMargin*interpolatedTime would always be 0.

To fix it, I used this calculation:

```
    joinDown = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnShopWireless.getLayoutParams();
            params.bottomMargin = (int)(newBottomMargin -(level3Height/2 * interpolatedTime)); 
            btnShopWireless.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
```